# How can I use Paw as a GraphQL client

Tags: paw-app

I've already used most popular GraphiQL client, but it lacks saving and categorizing queries.

Does Paw support making graphql request, and writing queries with auto-complete and type-hinting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Paw 3.2, GraphQL is now supported in the Body tab of a request.

With the ability to retrieve and explore the schema, via introspection.

Answer (score 5):

Paw does work as a GraphQL client, but it's not as full-featured as you'd like. As far as I can tell, while you can make any kind of GraphQL request, it doesn't support any kind of auto-complete or type-hinting.

---

The [GraphQL spec](http://facebook.github.io/graphql/) defines a way to query and execute data. However each website has their own way of letting you access that query interface.

For example, [GitHub's API](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/forming-calls/#communicating-with-graphql) uses a `POST` request with a JSON payload to send almost all its GraphQL queries, but [Facebook uses](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/) a more REST-like `GET`/`POST`/`DELETE` approach with path and query parameters.

Paw is more than capable of making and saving these types of requests.

### Big queries

One thing to be aware of is that GraphQL requests can get large when trying to fetch multiple, nested data models (get me all the `Comments` on `Posts` that were written by `User` X). Having a large query inside a single field in Paw's can get unwieldy. I recommend using Paw's [dynamic values](https://paw.cloud/docs/dynamic-values/introduction) and inserting a [file](https://paw.cloud/docs/dynamic-values/introduction) that contains your GraphQL query. This way you can write your queries without having to jam them on a single line or use tons of escape sequences.